# Water leaking through floor grout next to tub

Tags: shower, waterproofing, grout

We purchased a home last year. Found that there is a leak in the basement after the shower runs. Through several weeks of investigation, including opening walls and basement ceiling, we have located the source. At the back of the tub (where the shower sprays), a bit of water often runs over the edge of the tub. In the corner where the edge of the tub, the wall and the floor meet there is about 1" of grout between the floor tile and the edge of the tub. Water that drips down the side of the tub is just flowing straight through the grout then onto the subfloor under the tub. (See wet area in pic below.)

[image: wet]

So, that's the problem, but what's the solution?

Given the way other work was done at this house, I'm pretty sure no waterproofing membrane was laid down under the floor tile. But I really don't want to pull up the whole floor and do the tile job from scratch, even though that would probably be the best solution.

The idea I had is to take out the grout along the tub, allow the subfloor underneath to dry, then use silicone caulk (or something similar--I really don't want to buy a gallon of Redguard or whatever for this small area) to waterproof the subfloor. Then, re-grout.

I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Unfortunately water has a bad habit of spreading.  Might just be that small area that is wet or half or more of the subfloor under the tiles can be wet(possibly starting to rot or mould).